# How to develop Java sources in Eclipse when you use rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening,

I am learning how to develop nodes with rosjava and I am studying the package test_rosjava.

I am updating my new package helloworld and in the file CMakeList.txt, I have defined that my source folder is javasources:

```
add_java_source_dir(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/java)
```

With java files, I am thinking to develop with eclipse but I would like to know where is the library to add in buildpath in eclipse for the following packages which I saw in the examples:

```
AddTwoIntsClient.java  Listener.java        Talker.java  tester.cpp
AddTwoIntsServer.java  rosjava_test.launch  Testee.java

import ros.*;
import ros.communication.*;
```

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9916/how-to-develop-java-sources-in-eclipse-when-you-use-rosjava/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2011-05-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend switch to the new rosjava.  It is developed directly in Eclipse so there are more examples there of what to do.  Admittedly it is still very alpha and in-progress.l

http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1